# Class template specialization in child namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, template-specialization

There are few similar questions, but are about specializing class in *different* namespace.

Here I have piece of code, which compiles on MSVC, but does not compile on gcc, clang:

```
template<typename T>
struct type_of {};

class ClassA {};

template<>
struct type_of<ClassA> {
    using type = ClassA;
};

namespace space {

    class ClassBInNamespace {};

    template<typename T>
    class TemplateClassCInNamespace {};

    template<>
    struct type_of<ClassBInNamespace> {
        using type = ClassBInNamespace;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct type_of<TemplateClassCInNamespace<T>> {
        using type = /*does not compile with MSVC without namespace: space::*/TemplateClassCInNamespace<T>;
    };
}

int main(int, char*[]) {

    type_of<ClassA>::type classA;
    type_of<space::ClassBInNamespace>::type classB;
    type_of<space::TemplateClassCInNamespace<int>>::type classC;
}
```

So MSVC allowes type_of specialization in *child namespace of enclosing namespace (global)*, but has a weird problem when the class is template:

> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'TemplateClassCInNamespace'
>
> main.cpp(25): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Standard about this says:
*An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template. An explicit specialization whose declarator-id is not qualified shall be declared in the nearest enclosing namespace of the template, or, if the namespace is inline (7.3.1), any namespace from its enclosing namespace set. Such a declaration may also be a definition. If the declaration is not a definition, the specialization may be defined later (7.3.1.2).*

I understand the first sentence - I could specialized template in 'parent-namespace' of the template (so inversely than in example).
But I completely do not understand the second part..

Should specializing in child-namespace be allowed?
Is MSVC wrong to compile specialization of *type_of< ClassBInNamespace >* or to not compile *type_of< TemplateClassCInNamespace< T > >* in child-namespace?

Comment: Why do you think specializing in child-namespace is allowed?

Comment: I do not know it. 
I did so and MSVC did not complain so far, so I thought it works.
But when it stopped - I started checking :)
Honestly - I don't see a problem in this.
For me it's more natural, than specialization of a template defined in enclosed namespace. 
But of course, its 'for me' :p

Comment: MSVC is wrong to allow that because [it is forbidden in the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.expl.spec#2)